# Visual Studio Code and Debugging mode

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a small js file in the path /home/***/Downloads/main.js. The content of this file is:

```
console.log("Hello, world")
```

My launch.json file looks this way:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "/home/matan/Downloads",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "externalConsole": false,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "localhost",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null,
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": null
    }
]
```

}

and still I get the following error:

> Program 'nodejs /home/matan/Downloads/main.js' is not an absolute path; consider adding '${workspaceRoot}/' as a prefix to make it absolute.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
"cwd": "/home/matan/Downloads"
```

to

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
```